# How to make scene transition in SceneKit Xcode Playground, when any key is pressed?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift-playground

So I want to make a SceneKit project in playground, but now I am struggling to make a scene transition. The problem is that I want to make scene change when any keyboard is pressed, but don't know how to take keyboard as an input.
This is what I tried:

```
import Cocoa
import SceneKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let viewer: SCNView!
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 800, height: 600)
viewer = SCNView(frame: frame)
let menuScene: SCNScene!
menuScene = SCNScene(named: "Scenes.scnassets/Menu.scn")!
viewer.scene = menuScene
override public func keyUp(with event: NSEvent){
    viewer.scene = SCNScene(named: "Scenes.scnassets/ScenePR.scn")
}
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewer
```